# Proving Native American ancestry using DNA testing?

Tags: dna, native-american

I saw on *The Generation Project* where a man took a DNA test that showed he was some percentage Native American or was the chance that he as Native American.

Can a DNA test prove that I have Native American ancestry?

Comment: Does anyone remember the show? If someone does, hope they will suggest a descriptive reference.

Comment: This looks like the program being referenced. http://byutv.org/watch/5aa3f260-3043-47c6-81e4-a3f737ee34df/the-generations-project-ed

Comment: What about the Cherokee R- M269? Please explain

Answer (score 21):

There are several tests that can show if you have Native American ancestry.  I just posted a summary of the 3 core types of genealogical DNA tests in answer to another question, so please read here for general information on DNA testing:

[How can DNA testing aid me in my genealogy research?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/26/how-can-dna-testing-aid-me-in-my-genealogy-research)

Specifically, for Native American ancestry:

- Y-DNA: If you have Native American ancestry on your direct *paternal* line (your father's father's father etc), then you will have a Y-DNA haplogroup that has been found to be specific to Native Americans -- C3b, Q1a3a1, Q1a3a4
- mtDNA: If you have Native American ancestry on your direct *maternal* line (your mother's mother's mother etc), then you will have an mtDNA haplogroup that has been found to be specific to Native Americans -- certain subgroups of A, B, C, D and X.
- Autosomal: Provides biogeographical percentages of your overall ancestry, not limited to direct maternal or direct paternal line.  However, this test is limited in how many generations back it can detect a Native American ancestor.  Typically, if you had a full-blooded Native American great-great-grandparent or closer ancestor, you should have inherited enough of the NA ancestor's autosomal DNA for it to be detected by this test.  However, if the full-blooded NA ancestor was further back than great-great-grandparent, then you may or may not have inherited enough DNA from that ancestor to be detected by this test.

Comment: I don't think Ancestry does mtDNA or Y DNA though so you would have to find a different testing site if that's what the OP wants